# htaccess: how to deny complete access to an existing directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory, url-rewriting

How can I deny access to a directory in .htaccess?

I don't mean directory listing, I mean everything that is inside the directory along with the directory itself? It should give a 503 or 404 error.

I am talking about `/img-sys` and `/java-sys` which apparently do not exist (I did not create them), but still give a white screen when accessed rather than a 404 error.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO and should be on ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^(img-sys|java-sys) - [R=404]
```

Comment: Do you have a specific error page you want to redirect them to?

Comment: No, just a 404 response or a 503. I think, though, it wont work.. These folders do not really exist, which makes them somehow "system" or something, so the rewrite rules wont apply for them I believe..

Comment: Maybe you *are* getting a 404 for that page, just the 404 page is blank maybe? Rewrite rules will apply as long as there is nothing superseding them.

Comment: No, the 404 is not blank, but I think the system folders are not even going through the rewrite rules. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hmm no problem - sorry it didn't get resolved fully. There must be some app-specific reason it's not going through the rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it.  It'll just fail with a `403 Forbidden` HTTP response code.  Stick that in your `VirtualHost` block:

```
<LocationMatch "/(img|java)-sys">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</LocationMatch>
```